# How can I express object which should be 2 different classes at the same time

Tags: java, oop, interface, polymorphism

Today I had test in OOP and I was given the following task to code:

> Imagine you have two classes: Employee (which represents being an employee) and Ninja (which represents being a Ninja). An Employee has both state and behaviour; a Ninja has only behavior. You need to represent an employee who is also a ninja (a common problem in the real world). By creating only one interface and only one class (NinjaEmployee), show how you can do this without having to copy method implementation code from either of the original classes. Test your code in main method

I did not really understand the problem well, but this is the solution I came with (I know it's not what was asked):

I created 4 classes except main. As Employee has state and behaviour I came up with this code:

```
public class Employee {
    private int ID;
    private String Name;
    private double salary;

    public Employee(int ID, String Name, double salary) {
        this.ID = ID;
        this.Name = Name;
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public int getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(int ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String Name) {
        this.Name = Name;
    }

    public double getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(double salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public void startWorking() {
        System.out.println("Started Working");
    }
}
```

Class ninja has only behaviour:

```
public class Ninja {

    public Ninja(){}


    public void moveNinja(){
        System.out.println("Ninja moved");
    }
}
```

Class NinjaEmployee:

```
public class NinjaEmployee extends Employee implements MyInterface {

    public NinjaEmployee(int ID, String Name, double salary) {
        super(ID, Name, salary);
    }

    public void moveNinja() {
        System.out.println("Ninja Moved");
    }

}
```

Interface which does not make sense in my code:

```
public interface MyInterface {

   public void moveNinja();
   public void startWorking();

}
```

Main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    MyInterface em = new NinjaEmployee(123,"Sandro",1000000);
    em.moveNinja();
    em.startWorking();
}
```

My question is following:

1) Specifically/Technically what was asked in test?

2) What would be correct approach/code for given problem?

Comment: @OleV.V. Do you think it is correct approach for given problem? I feel like something is missing because I lack theoretical  knowledge in some concepts

Comment: “…without having to copy method implementation code from either of the original classes”. You have copied the `moveNinja` method from `Ninja` into `NinjaEmployee`, so as I see it you are not fully fulfilling the requirements. I would think composition (if you know what it means).

Answer (score 1):

**Nice question.** 
The key point of the question is:

1. we should use one interface.
2. Ninja class should have some methods (not attributes).

So we should try to use these key point.

I provide a class diagram below:

[image]

**First of all:** We have `Employee` class and implement it like other simple classes. It has some implemented attributes and classes.

**Secondly**: We have an Interface named `Ninja_Interface` that have some method declarations about ninja. (`moveNinja1` and `moveNinja2`)

**Thirdly**: `Ninja` Class that implemented (or Realized) `Nijna_Interface` and have some implementation of any method declarations in `Ninja_Interface`.

**Fourthly**: the `NinjaEmployee` class. It inherited from `Employee`. So it has all `Employee`'s attributes and methods. Also it implements `Ninja_Interface`. So it should implements all `Ninja_Interface` methods declarations. On the other hand, `NinjaEmployee` have an instance of `Ninja` (notice that `Ninja` class implements all `Ninja_Interface` methods). 
**So**, In `Ninja_Employee` class, in implementation of `Ninja_Interface` methods, we can use `Ninja` instance methods to call.

For example some parts of `NinjaEmployee` is like below code:

```
private Ninja ninja=new Ninja();
public void moveNinja1()
{
    ninja.moveNinja1();
}
public void moveNinja2()
{
    ninja.moveNinja2();
}
```

**Main question** is: why `Ninja` class **should have only some methods**? 
It is because of `Ninja` class is just the implementations of `Ninja_Interface` methods and there no need to have attributes. So **instances of `Ninja` class are the same**. So we can declare `Ninja` attribute in `NinjaEmployee` as **static attribute**.

**Finally**: we can add some attributes of ninja into `NinjaEmployee` class too.

Comment: I think you’re helping too much. The OP would learn more from solving the assignment himself/herself. Your approach is very good.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know correct answer (task is kinda not very strictly defined, there is some unclear moments), but i would do something like this:

```
public interface IAmNinja {
   public void moveNinja();
}

public interface IAmEmployer {
   public void startWorking();
}

public class NinjaEmployee implements IAmNinja, IAmEmployer {
    private Ninja _ninja;
    private Employer _employer;

    public NinjaEmployee(int ID, String Name, double salary) {
        _employer = new Employer(ID, Name, salary);
        _ninja = new Ninja();
    }

    public void moveNinja() {
        _ninja.moveNinja();
    }

    public void startWorking() {
        _employer.startWorking();
    }
}
```

Comment: only one interface??

Comment: Its ugly :) maybe you are more result-oriented, but I prefer better design. Yes, we can use inheritance as a nasty hack for pulling implementation, we can even end up with 0-1000 interfaces, but... you wanna do programming or hacking?

Answer (score -1):

You cant create 1 object  of 2 class es
You can extend class so whenever child class is instantiated it calls parent class constructor
Then You can create object of another class in that constructor

Add employees in array and add option to add employee in ninja? 1.yes or 2.no?
if yes , add to ninja..then in main method print names of ninja using for loop one by one

Comment: I know that I can't, original task is given if you read post carefully and I want to know would correct approach would be for given problem